# What is the name or number of this chip on this PCB?

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit

We are trying to repair this pcb. We found that someone deleted the number or name of this chip which needs to be replaced anyone has idea ?

[image: what is the name of the highlighted part ?]

[image: this is the circuitry]
[image]

Comment: Looks like a voltage regulator. Do you have any idea of what voltage the output should have been? 5V, 12? Etc.

Comment: It is not working so we can't know it at the moment 5V or 12V but there is 16V inscription on power supply.

Comment: I would say it's either a Power Amplifier or an Opto Mos

Comment: Or simply a dual Channel Mosfet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it have two leads to the PCB plus the thermal lug - so 3 terminals total?  If so, it could be a transistor of some sort.

EDIT 1:

OK, 5 (maybe 6?) terminals total.  Thanks, I had trouble seeing that in the pictures.  So it's probably not a transistor.

Comment: It has total of 5 leads to the PCB other than the thermal lug

Comment: why exactly is this answer accepted? Did it solve the problem?